# How to apply live gaussain blur effect to UWP apps?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

Recently I was learning UWP and trying to build a simple demo, and I just want to generate a simple live blur effect like Aero. It's sometimes useful(eg.real time camera filters), so I made an idea like this:

First I imported the win2D library and placed a **CanvasAnimatedControl** on the RootGrid:

```
<canvas:CanvasAnimatedControl x:Name="BlurLayer" Draw="BlurLayer_Draw" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

The resource of this blur layer is a **Frame**:

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" LayoutUpdated="MainFrame_LayoutUpdated" 
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

and every time the frame has updated, the **MainFrame_LayoutUpdated** method try to save a shortcut uses RenderTargetBitmap, however, the win2D can't receive this object as its CanvasBitmap, so it is converted to byte[] and saved;

```
    RenderTargetBitmap renderer = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    CanvasBitmap bitmap;
    byte[] RendererStream;
    public static int FrameWidth;
    public static int FrameHeight;
    public ICanvasImage RenderFinal;
    public bool Frame_Updated = false;
private async void MainFrame_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
        await renderer.RenderAsync(MainFrame);
        FrameWidth = renderer.PixelWidth;
        FrameHeight = renderer.PixelHeight;
        RendererStream = WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(await renderer.GetPixelsAsync());
        if (FrameHeight != 0)
            Frame_Updated = true;
    }
```

In the **BlurLayer_Draw** method, just refresh and apply blur effect:
private void BlurLayer_Draw(ICanvasAnimatedControl sender,

```
CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
        {
            if (Frame_Updated)
            {
                bitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(sender, RendererStream, FrameWidth, FrameHeight, DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized);
                RenderFinal = new GaussianBlurEffect
                                 {
                                      Source = bitmap
                                 };
                RenderFinal.BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard;
                RenderFinal.BlurAmount = 8.0f;
                Frame_Updated = false;
            }
            if (RenderFinal != null)
                args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(RenderFinal);
        }
```

when all this done, it worked.
but this solution was really terrible, the win2D Canvas was seriously delayed.
So, what should I do to make it high performance?

Comment: Maybe SharpDX might help you? http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-direct2d1-effects-gaussianblur It uses DirectX and should be more performant.

Comment: I have a blog post about really fast blurring with Lumia Imaging SDK http://igrali.com/2015/09/26/using-swapchainpanelrenderer-to-improve-real-time-rendering-in-lumia-imaging-sdk-3/ and the project is also on GitHub https://github.com/igrali/PropertyDescriptions maybe that will help you!

Comment: @sibbl         I'd like to try it.

Comment: @igrali        I read your blog and tried your sample, that's really fast and just what I want. thx.

Comment: @EmbraceZXS ok great! I also posted it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Making my comment the official answer: use Lumia Imaging SDK. It has a BlurEffect that's really fast if used for real-time rendering with SwapChainPanelRenderer. I wrote about it in my blog post [Using SwapChainPanelRenderer to improve real-time rendering in Lumia Imaging SDK 3](http://igrali.com/2015/09/26/using-swapchainpanelrenderer-to-improve-real-time-rendering-in-lumia-imaging-sdk-3/) where I used exactly BlurEffect as an example. Full source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/igrali/PropertyDescriptions).

It comes down to calling `RenderAsync` on a `SwapChainPanelRenderer` instance whenever the blur KernelSize value changes to the new slider value.

```
private async void EffectRangeSlider_OnValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.renderer != null)
    {
        this.viewModel.blur.KernelSize = (int)e.NewValue;

        await this.renderer.RenderAsync();
    }
}
```